# "condition expected: <" on zsh in Mac OSX(ML)

Tags: macos, shell

I'm learning shell scripts on the zsh on Mac OSX(ML).

When tring

```
test good \< bad
```

it gives

```
zsh: condition expected: <
```

Can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you not just use flags to test?

```
% test 1 -lt 2 && echo 'it\'s less! yay!'
% test 1 -gt 2 && echo 'ohnoes, math is broken'
```

Incidentally, using your test here, 'test 1 \< 2' works in `bash` and fails in `zsh`. Looking at the zsh docs (`zshbuiltin` among others), it seems that `<` is in fact the right operator for less than, but go ahead and use the `-lt` and `-gt`. If you must use the left angle bracket, use this syntax:

```
% [[ 1 < 2 ]] && echo 'hooray for angle brackets!'
```

which seems to work on my zsh, which is `zsh 4.3.11 (i386-apple-darwin12.0)`.

Comment: Exactly. Note that `test` and `[ … ]` are documented in the `zsh` man page as being “added for compatibility”; so they’re not preferred, whereas `[[` is.